# Rails limits list of time zones to "meaningful" 146, how to extend it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I need to add *Beirut* to the default list of time zones in rails. Now code like `ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Beirut"]` throws an exception, but I want it to work as usual.

I monkey patched ActiveSupport::TimeZone in initializer:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING = 
   ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.merge({"Beirut" => "EET"})
```

But it throws warning every time rails app starts, cos I am changing value of constant. And I can't change MAPPING hash, cos it's frozen.

Is there a good way to extend list of default Rails time zones?

Comment: If you need to look at Rails source, here it is: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/df3bda2c517b13e6f346c9204ec2e9422c77ae7f/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb#L377

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that.

- EET isn't a fully formed IANA time zone identifier.
- Lebanon doesn't follow EET in the same way that the other EU countries do.  Specifically, they do not transition to and from daylight saving time at the same points.  For details, you can compare [Beirut, Lebanon](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=34&year=2013) with [Bucharest, Romania](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=49&year=2013).  Romania is an EU country, so it will follow the EET/EEST rules perfectly, while Lebanon will not.
- Lebanon has it's own rich history of time zone changes, which are all tracked and maintained by the `Asia/Beirut` time zone identifier.  You don't want to disregard that and assume current EET rules have been around forever.  You can review the history for Lebanon in the sources for the TZ database, [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/b0cde690c66b6c91404f738059f940df3fc1e4a8/asia#L1612-1640).
- Rails time zones are rather strange and non-standard.  Read more near the bottom of [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

My best advice to you would be to *not* use Rails time zone identifiers, and use the [TZInfo gem](http://tzinfo.github.io/) instead, where you can properly use the `Asia/Beirut` time zone.